# PostgreSQL, Hibernate, IntelliJ IDEA - Creating a Project

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have created a database with PostgreSQL and would like to create a terminal/console application, where I can input commands to read data out of the database.

I started setting up IntelliJ and followed this tutorial:

http://in.relation.to/2015/07/15/intellij-idea-mac-and-orm/

And now have this:

[image: Hibernate-ORM Project]

1. Is the Hibernate-ORM my project folder where I can create a new class? If so, do I have to copy this whole folder for every new project I make?
   I tried right clicking into the buildSRC folder but it doesn't offer me to make a new class, only modules and files.
2. Do I have to use Groovy or can I do everything in Java?

Comment: Looks like you have cloned the Hibernate source code repo, rather than using Hibernate in your application. Read a different guide.

Comment: If you want to implement a generic SQL client Hibernate is most definitely not the right choice for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have cloned [the hibernate-orm repo](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) which is the source code of Hibernate library. If you would like to develop a sample application using Hibernate/JPA check out:

- [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)
- [Spring Boot, MySQL, JPA,
  Hibernate Restful CRUD API Tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/)